# image load invalid destination position for blit

Tags: python, pygame

I want to blit an image but for some reason pygame displays this error. Any ideas?

```
import pygame

def main():

    pygame.init()
    knight = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Sathesh Previn\OneDrive\Game Codes\RPG\Knight Sprite.png')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    done = False
    white = (255, 255, 255)

    while done == False:

        screen.fill(white)
        screen.blit(knight, 100, 100)
        pygame.display.update() 

main()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a tuple, list or pygame.Rect as the `dest` argument to [pygame.Surface.blit](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit).

```
screen.blit(knight, (100, 100))
```